# Adding Shapes to GridPane results in wrong Position

Tags: javafx, gridpane

I got the task to draw some points on a map. Wrote some code but currently every point I create via shapes will be added to the wrong position inside of my gridpane. Oh and I'm using JavaFX.

I added an imageView to the index 0,0 of my GridPane and every point is created through x and y position of the MouseEvent on the imageView.
After that I added the created point as a child of the GridPane and it's displayed at the center of the y-axis of the first grid. 
Tried different things like anchorPanes and canvas but can't seem to get it working.

Code of my View:
http://pastebin.com/dCb7EN4d

Code of my Main:
http://pastebin.com/vp5tzxkG

I hope that's enough ^^'
pls help!

Greetings,
Ben

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When asking questions of the type "Why isn't this code working?", please: (1) create a minimal, executable, example that contains only enough code to recreate the problem (i.e. post something executable, but don't post your whole project). See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for details. (2) Post your code in the question, instead of linking to it. This means your question will still make sense (for future users) even if pastebin stops working (or gets overloaded, as it is now...).

Answer (score 0):

`GridPane` is a managed layout: it will position nodes that are added to it via the properties you set (using defaults if you don't set them). So when you add your circles to the grid pane, since you don't set any properties, it will place it in cell (0,0) and align it within that cell using default settings; i.e. it ignores the `centerX` and `centerY` properties.

What you should really do here is use a layout that does not manage the positioning of the nodes for you, such as a [`Pane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) (or possibly a [`Group`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html)). You can put the `ImageView` and the `Circle`s in the pane, and then place the pane in the rest of your layout (in the scroll pane, I think).

The other option you have is to call `setManaged(false)` on the nodes you add to the `GridPane` in order to instruct the `GridPane` not to position them, though this feels like more of a workaround.